# Dependency Injection - Injecting The Container, Or Individual Dependencies?

Tags: php, oop, slim

When using Dependency Injection should dependencies be passed into a constructor individually, or is it acceptable to pass the entire DI container?

For example ... I have a repository called 'UserRepository'. It contains the following methods:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Repositories;

use \MyApp\Models\User;

class UserRepository {

    private $ci;

    public function __construct($ci)
    {
        $this->ci = $ci;
    }

    public function hashPassword($password)
    {
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [
            'cost' => 15
        ]);
    }

    public function create($firstname, $lastname, $email, $password)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname'  => $lastname,
            'email'     => $email,
            'password'  => $this->hashPassword($password)
        ]);

        return $user;
    }

    public function activateUser($userID)
    {
        $user = User($userID);
        $user->email_verified = 1;
        $user->save();

        $verification = $user->verification();
        $verification->is_used = 1;
        $verification->validated_at = $this->ci->get('Carbon')::now();
        $verification->save();
    }
}
```

The `Carbon` dependancy is available because I've passed in the `Pimple` container. I can access any dependency in this way (so long as they're registered).

I'm using `Slim3` which promotes this sort of DI. But, in applications like `Laravel` I see dependencies being passed into the constructor individually.

Any advice?

Comment: when you pass the entire DI container as dependency, you call it "service locator", and yes, it's a bad practice.

Comment: @Federkun thanks, that makes sense. I believe Pimple is a service locator, so right now I'm stuck with that. I didn't know the two were different. It seems I'm not the only one confused: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/3x9e48/service_locator_dependency_injection/

Comment: no, Pimple isn't a service locator, but _you can use it as Service Locator_

Comment: If you could put it as an answer with maybe a few lines on with Service Locators are bad practice I'd accept.

Comment: I'll (when I've a moment to write it)

Comment: PHP-DI is a far better container than Pimple. In all my Slim based APIs I use PHP-DI, and just pass all the dependencies in the Constructor, making my code a decoupled as I can. See http://php-di.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the Dependency Injection Containers to a class, you call it "Service Locator". With a Service Locator your class is *still* responsible to instantiate its dependencies, and as such you should also unit test it. But how? Your object can't exist without a service locator, and test it isn't easy. If you pass the dependency into the constructor you can just mock them.

In your class you have this:

```
$verification->validated_at = $this->ci->get('Carbon')::now();
```

where `Carbon` is the service name. Now you should keep in mind that the Service Locator that you inject to the class require a service with that name, and it should returns an instance of the `Carbon\Carbon` class. What if your Service Locator has a missing `Carbon` service or what if it returns a whole different object? You should test it with something like this to be sure not to break anything:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf(Carbon\Carbon::class, $container->get('Carbon'));
```

and more important, if you want reuse your object somewhere else you need to implement a specific service locator implementation.

By using a DIC your object isn't responsible to instantiate its dependencies anymore:

```
$container['user.repository'] = function ($c) {
    return new UserRepository($c['Carbon']);
};
```

Your class is more reusable and writing tests is more easier.

Comment: Great explanation. The last part confuses me though. In my case I have `dependencies.php` file. In your last example `user.repository` I have a similar setup. I have a `Logger` container that returns a new instance of `Monolog`. But, I still access them using `$this->ci->get('Logger');` from within Services, or Actions. Should I be accessing `Logger` in another way?

Comment: Do not misunderstand me, a service locator isn't an antipattern, I often use it when I write a symfony's controller. Sure, it hides dependencies and _it's not a best practice_, but it's the pragmatic way to do it. Use it where it makes sense